# Why is this LINQ query not executed when using foreach?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, foreach, deferred-execution

When creating new objects in a LINQ statement, for example:

```
var list = new List<string>() { "a", "b", "c" };
var created = from i in list select new A();
```

With class A looking like this:

```
class A
{
    public string Label;
}
```

And then modifying properties in A with a foreach loop:

```
foreach (var c in created) {
    c.Label = "Set";
}
```

Why are the values not set when accessing the objects in the `IEnumerable` afterwards. E.g. the following assertion fails:

```
Assert.AreEqual("Set", created.ElementAt(2).Label);
```

I wonder why this happens. I would expect the foreach-statement to execute the query, and trigger the creation of the objects. MSDN documentation states: ["Execution of the query is deferred until the query variable is iterated over in a foreach or For Each loop"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738633.aspx).

I have reproduced this behavior with .NET 4.5 and Mono 3.2.0. Calling `ToList` on the `IEnumerable` before accessing the created object makes this problem go away.

Comment: It's the opposite of "not executed" - it's executed *twice* - and when it's executed a second time, a *new* set of `A`s are created.

Comment: Because `created` is a query not a collection. Everytime you access it you execute it again. So if you enumerate the query again after the `foreach` you will get a fresh new set of `IEnumerable<A>`. That's the nature of deferred execution. If you would have queried an existing collection of `A`'s you would change existing objects which would be persistent.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's happening because `created` is a query, not a result. So, every time you enumerate it, you're evaluating the `Select` over again from scratch.

If you want this to work, make `created` an actual list, rather than just an `IEnumerable` representing a query.

For example, add:

```
created = created.ToList();
```

You say:

> I would expect the foreach-statement to execute the query, and trigger the creation of the objects

This is exactly what is happening.  The problem is the creation of the objects happens every time you iterate over `created`, not just the first time.  Since the `ElementAt()` method iterates over `created`, it's just creating new `A`s again.